# How to get intersection by a value in java for a list of Objects?

Tags: java, list, intersection

Structure of the class:

```
class MyObject{
private String key;
private int value;
private int num;
}
```

Creating a list of objects:

```
List<MyObject> a = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
```

Contents of the list of objects:

```
"Einstein",12,1
"Princeton",12,4
"Einstein",16,3
"Princeton",16,7
"Einstein",19,6
"Princeton",22,6
"Quantum",12,3
"Quantum",16,6
```

For Input: `"Einstein","Princeton","Quantum"`

Checking if a key is present in all value fields, if so add up the num field. In this case Einstein, Princeton, Quantum is present only in value 12. So adding up the num field will give 8. Hence,

Expected output list:

```
12,8
```

Basically I am trying to get the intersection of value field of the object and summation of the corresponding num field. How to achieve this?

EDIT:
List xy = Arrays.asList(terms); // terms are the input

```
    Map<Integer, Integer> check = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {

            if (xy.contains(a.get(i).getKey())) {

                Integer sum = check.get(a.get(i).getNum());
                if (sum == null)
                    sum = 0;
                sum += a.get(i).getNum();
                check.put(a.get(i).getValue(), sum);
            }

    }
```

List Contents:

```
Key: british Value: 899816511 Occ: 8
Key: naren Value: 899816511 Occ: 1
Key: einstein Value: 899816511 Occ: 1
Key: british Value: 562115287 Occ: 1
Key: einstein Value: 2056958632 Occ: 1
Key: british Value: 2056958632 Occ: 1
Key: einstein Value: 1426519040 Occ: 1
Key: british Value: 1426519040 Occ: 5
```

Input: `"british","naren","einstein"`

Output:

```
{1426519040=5, 562115287=1, 2056958632=1, 899816511=1}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "intersection"?

Comment: "intersection" isn't the right word for what you're trying to do. Why isn't `19,6` and `22,6` in the output? Because there must be 2 elements of some `value` for it to show up? What if there's more than 2?

Comment: the num field is not used. Only the value field, hence 19,6 and 22,6 is not considered.

Comment: Didn't you get `12,5` from `12,1` and `12,4` (i.e. `12,1+4`)?

Comment: Use a HashMap<Integer, Integer>. Loop through the ArrayList and update the map on each iteration. Use value as the key and num as the value in the map. So basically Integer sum = map.get(value); if(sum == null) sum = 0; sum += num; map.put(value, sum);

Comment: @Dukeling Yes. I have modified the example.

Comment: Pretty much what @SpiderPig said, except, for each entry, first check if the `key`'s contained in the input.

Comment: I have made an edit to the question. I could not get the desired output still. Am i missing something?

Comment: Remove the if. It needs to update the sum every time. Not just when the value is contained in the map. Also it should be Integer sum = check.get(a.get(i).getValue());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written a "solution" code, based on what I think you are after. Try and modify according to your needs.
Do notice that there are two results:
16,16
12,8

```
private static class MyObject {
    private String key;
    private int value;
    private int num;

    public MyObject(String key, int value, int num) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
        this.num = num;
    }
    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }
    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public int getNum() {
        return num;
    }
}

private static class KeysAndSum {
    private Set<String> keys = new HashSet<String>();
    private int sum;

    public Set<String> getKeys() {
        return keys;
    }
    public void addKey(String key) {
        keys.add(key);
    }
    public int getSum() {
        return sum;
    }
    public void addNum(int num) {
        sum += num;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<MyObject> a = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
    a.add(new MyObject("Einstein", 12, 1));
    a.add(new MyObject("Princeton", 12, 4));
    a.add(new MyObject("Einstein", 16, 3));
    a.add(new MyObject("Princeton", 16, 7));
    a.add(new MyObject("Einstein", 19, 6));
    a.add(new MyObject("Princeton", 22, 6));
    a.add(new MyObject("Quantum", 12, 3));
    a.add(new MyObject("Quantum", 16, 6));

    List<String> requiredKeys = new ArrayList<String>();
    requiredKeys.add("Einstein");
    requiredKeys.add("Princeton");
    requiredKeys.add("Quantum");

    Map<Integer, KeysAndSum> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (MyObject obj : a) {
        KeysAndSum keysAndSum;
        if (map.containsKey(obj.getValue())) {
            keysAndSum = map.get(obj.getValue());
        } else {
            keysAndSum = new KeysAndSum();
            map.put(obj.getValue(), keysAndSum);
        }
        keysAndSum.addKey(obj.getKey());
        keysAndSum.addNum(obj.getNum());
    }
    for (Entry<Integer, KeysAndSum> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        boolean allFound = true;
        for (String reqKey : requiredKeys) {
            if (!entry.getValue().getKeys().contains(reqKey)) {
                allFound = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (allFound) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ","
                    + entry.getValue().getSum());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: expected is only 12,8 since all the three words are present only in 12.

Comment: @Naren No they are not. Inspect your own example - you have all three words in both 12 and 16.